# Can't Find Theme

Tags: ubuntu, theme

I am trying out Ubuntu Linux and want to change the default theme.  I saw the a theme site. I saw a really good menu bar and thought that downloading the theme would allow me to have that look. But, the theme only change the color. Can anyone tell me how to change the look of my menu bar to look like the picture below?

[image: Picture]

For reference, I would only like to have one menu bar and not 2.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that the Global menu bar in Ubuntu.

Comment: That's just it, I'm not sure.  The one of the top has the close and minimize buttons on one sleek bar.  Mine has two menu bars with one on top and one on the bottom.  I haven't found a setting that would change it if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the first screenshot is from plain GNOME 3 desktop environment. Ubuntu by default uses Unity on top of GNOME which adds the global menu bar. 
If you would like to remove the global menu bar, follow instructions in this [link](http://lifehacker.com/5887462/how-to-disable-ubuntus-annoying-global-menu-bar). Basically you just need to run this command to remove few Ubuntu packages -

```
sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt
```

Logout and log back in or restart open applications.

Another option is to install different Linux flavor which uses Gnome 3 desktop environment like [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/) if you are not specific about Ubuntu. Ubuntu also has a GNOME spin but not very sure about the desktop layout.